# charset problem with new custom table

Tags: database

I have problem with charset in mySQl custom table.

The new table does not use proper charset when new entries are being made.

my wordpress settings

define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_polish_ci');

and my create tabel function

```
global $wpdb;
global $bLink_db_version;

global $charset_collate;
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();    

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'bLink';

// make sure that the table doe not exist already
if( $wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $table_name . "'") !=  $table_name)
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,   
        url text NOT NULL,
        lname text NOT NULL,
        lcomment text NOT NULL,            
        ltag ENUM('GEN', 'POL', 'FIN', 'BOG', 'WEL') NOT NULL default 'GEN',
        lenable ENUM('Y', 'N') NOT NULL default 'Y',
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)) $charset_collate;";

    // calling dbDelta to execute sql directly, which cant migrate database
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
```

}

What could be wrong?